Why aren't my cookies persistent on subdomains?
I have an MERN app with a front end deployed on onrender.com and backend deployed on onrender.com.
I am attempting to use cookies and jwt for authentication but am having a lot of trouble with cookies being persistent. For example, I would log in, and be directed to my login backend route through axios with the following:
axios.post("https://backend.onrender.com/login", { username, password }, { withCredentials: true })
My backend route for login is the following:
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Trying to login...");
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await Users.findOne({ email: username });
    if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
        console.log('Logged in');
        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, admin: user.role }, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '3h' });

        const expirationDate = new Date();
        expirationDate.setTime(expirationDate.getTime() + (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 2 hours expiration

        res.cookie('token', token, {
            path: "/",
            sameSite: 'none',
            secure: true,
            expires: expirationDate,
        });

        res.send({ success: true, user: username, token: token });
    } else {
        console.log("Failed to Login");
        res.send({ success: false, message: 'Invalid Input: Incorrect Email/Password!' });
    }
});

This is my cors settings:
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["https://frontend.onrender.com", "http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
}));

The cookie gets set but I also get this warning in my cookies tab in dev tools:
Warning for Cookie
I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening so any help would mean a lot!
I have tried on local host and it seems to work fine.

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
